# SuperClass and SonClass

Tags: java

I have a SuperClass Employee and a Subclass Manager extends Employee with tribute Name.

Now I want to use instanceof while I go over an array of Employee

Example:

```
  while (employee[i]!=null){   
      if (employee[i] instanceof Manager)
      here is my problem"!!
```

I want to sysout a Manager atribute "Name":

```
sysout("Name: "+employee[i].name)
```

but it says create name in Employee.. why if it extends employee and already used instanceof...I tried Casting like this (Manager)employee[i].name but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cast needs to be applied to the value on which you are accessing the field.

```
((Manager)employee[i]).name
```

You were using it like

```
(Manager)employee[i].name
```

which attempted to apply the cast to the value returned by accessing the field `name`.